# How to Deploy a JBoss ESB on a Jboss AS

Tags: jboss, soa, jboss-esb

I am Trying to deploy Jboss esb over Jboss AS using Ant. but i am getting the following error and it is giving me a build fail. I certainly have changed the .Properties file with the correct Server home and server config paths.
Below is the error i am getting

Also I have Jboss 5.1.0 AS and Jbossesb 4.1.0
I am not sure what changes do i need to make with my build.xml file.

```
C:\jbossesb-4.10\install>ant deploy
Buildfile: C:\jbossesb-4.10\install\build.xml

check.deploy.props:

dependencies.source:

dependencies.jbossesb:

dependencies:

init.bindings.props:

undeploy.bindings:

undeploy.jbossas5:

undeploy.jbossas6:

undeploy:

BUILD FAILED
C:\jbossesb-4.10\install\build.xml:480: Directory does not exist: C:\jbossesb-4.10\install\jboss-5.1.0.GA\server\all\lib
```

Answer (score 0):

You've probably set bad server path in property file. Did you unpack server to "C:\jbossesb-4.10\install\jboss-5.1.0.GA\" directory?

You need to set the path to jboss-as directory. Correct may be something like this.

```
C:\jbossesb-4.10\install\jboss-5.1.0.GA\jboss-as\
```

Comment: No I have not. My server location is C:\jboss-5.1.0.GA\server\all\lib and that of ESB is C:\jbossesb-4.10\install. My Propertiy file has path org.jboss.esb.server.home= C:\jboss-5.1.0.GA and org.jboss.esb.server.config=all. I do not know why is it looking for that Directory. i did not make any change in the Build.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

In order to deploy jboss-esb on to jboss-as you need to have **deployment.properties file** in

your install folder of jboss-esb (for ex: \jbossesb-4.6\jbossesb-4.6\install)

in that deployment properties file you need to set your **jboss-as home**

ex: org.jboss.esb.server.home=D:/J Boss Book Installs/jboss-5.1.0.GA-jdk6/jboss-5.1.0.GA

NOTE: the direction of slash is **very important** it should be **forward slash(/)**  (as specified in example above) for it get indexed in to the given server.home location .

**Otherwise** you will get **directory doesn't exist** errors just like the one you specified above in your question .

Check your deployment.properties file and correct server.home it would probably resolve your error !!!