# Deploy JBoss ESB on JBoss AS get BUILD FAILED

Tags: deployment, jboss, esb

At first excuse me because my question sample asked in this link: [How to Deploy a JBoss ESB on a Jboss AS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14305859/how-to-deploy-a-jboss-esb-on-a-jboss-as), But I can not post any comment on it and it does not have a best answer yet or any useful solution!

I'm using ubuntu 11.04,my server is jboss-as-7.1.1.Final with jbossesb-4.11, I followed readme.txt file on Install folder of jbossesb-4-11, but after run "ant deploy" command I get this output:

```
user@computer:~/Library/jbossesb-4.11/install$ ant deploy

    Buildfile: /home/user/Library/jbossesb-4.11/install/build.xml

    check.deploy.props:

    dependencies.source:

    dependencies.jbossesb:

    dependencies:

    init.bindings.props:

    undeploy.bindings:

    undeploy.jbossas5:

    undeploy.jbossas6:

    undeploy:

    BUILD FAILED
    /home/user/Library/jbossesb-4.11/install/build.xml:574: Directory does not exist: /home/user/Library/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/server/default/lib
```

I specified jboss server path in deployment.properties file correctly but I don't know what's the problem!
In additional, In help pdf books there is a command: "cp -pR all all.original" (before run "ant deply") that shows there is a [all] folder in the [jboss-as-7.1.1.Final] folder, But I don't have such a folder in my server folder!

Thanks in advance for any help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JBoss ESB does not support deployment on AS 7.